# Laravel 5.4: how to save checked chekboxes value in database in a single column

Tags: php, checkbox, laravel-5.4

Say, i have a table named Medical_test. I want to save some test names using checkbox value.
Suppose, my view look like this:

```
<form action="{{ route('savetestnames')}}" method="post">
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Blood Test">Blood Test<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="X-ray">X-ray<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Ultrasonography">ultrasonography
</form>
```

Now i select 1st two checkboxes that is blood test & x-ray. How can i save them in my database using controller? Anyone please help.

**EDIT :**
say, my controller look like this:

```
public function SavePatientTests(Request $request)
{
    $tests = new Test();
   // what will be the code here
}
```

Comment: u will only receved them in post if they are checked. so if receved in post then insert else do nothing

Comment: @Purushottamzende i have edited my question. can you tell me what will be the code in controller for storing values?

Comment: @Purushottamzende i solved this. Thank you :)